# how to pass session parameter from jquery to ASHX handler

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net

Below is my Jquery code and I would like to pass Session paramater e.g. Session["ID"].
Jquery calls ASHX page

All below parameters are working fine and the session parameter has a value, but how can I pass session paramater from Jquery?

So below code "paramater Sessionparameter" should be replaced with Session["ID"] or something like that. How can I do that?

please advice?

```
   $('input[name$=btnTab1Save]').click(
             function (e) {
                 // debugger;
                 // AJAX call to the handler
                 $.post(
                    'Consulting.ashx',
                 // data to the handler in the form of QueryString
                    {
                    tab: 'tab1',
                    // id is the second column within the row
                    Ilac_id: prevRow.find('td:eq(0)').text(),
                    ID: SESSION_PARAMATER,
                    begindate: $('input[name$=begindate]').val(),
                    weigth: $('input[name$=weigth]').val(),
                    continue: true,
                    freq: $('input[name$=freq]').val(),
                    reason: $('input[name*=radListreason]:checked').val(),
                    freq2: $('input[name$=radListfreq2]:checked').val(),
                    freetext: $('input[name$=freetext]').val()
                },
                 // callback function
                 // data is the JSON object
                    function (data) {
                        if (data.Success) {
                            // close the tab
                        }
                    },
                    "json"
                );
             });
```

I can read my parameters like Convert.Toint(context.Request.Form["ID"]));

```
 data.weigth = Convert.ToInt32(context.Request.Form["weigth"]);
```

I tried : `'<%= Session["ID"] .ToString() %>'`, but it's not working....

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If the information is in the session, the ASHX can access directly the session content.

You need to implement `IReadOnlySessionState` and you will be fine.

```
<% @ webhandler language="C#" class="MyClass" %>

using System;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.SessionState;

public class MyClass: IHttpHandler, IReadOnlySessionState
{
   public bool IsReusable { get { return true; } }

   public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext ctx)
   {
       ctx.Response.Write(ctx.Session["ID"]);
   }
}
```

Comment: @Daok... thanks this works great. Just explain why I've to set the isReusable to true... it was false in my code (copied from internet).. please explain this property reason for true.. thanks

Comment: The 'IsReusable' method is set to true by default and indicates whether another request can use the IHttpHandler instance. So in your case you can put it as false or true, it won't really matter.

Answer (score 4):

The way to do it, if it is not sensitive data, would be to write the value of Session["ID"] to a javascript variable and then use the variable to post the data to the ASHX handler. Something like this:

```
var sessionVariable = '<%=HttpContext.Current.Session["ID"].ToString()%>';
```

And then:

```
 ID: sessionVariable, // etc ...
```

Comment: +1 for putting **if it is not sensitive data** on your answer.

Comment: Well, session information are stored in the URL or in a COOKIE. Session should never use sensitive information, even if not printed in the Javascript.

Comment: @Daok `Session should never use sensitive information` is a bit drastic; I mean, you can put both, sensitive and non-sensitive data in Session. For caching purposes, for example.

Comment: ;) You can try to "cache" the user credit card information... but in my point of view, the session is not for caching, neither for sensitive information...

Comment: @lcarus/@tugberk: I tried but I get error in the handler : Input string was not in a correct format. When I look in debugger (watch) the value in ASHX is "<%=HttpContext.Current.Session[\"ID\"].ToString()%>".  so it doesn't pass the value but the syntax code/programming code to ASHX

Comment: @mesut, it works for me. I did this on my `Default.aspx` page:   `Session["ID"] = "yadda yadda";` and then this on my landing page: `var session = '<%=HttpContext.Current.Session["ID"].ToString()%>';` and when I looked at the source of my landing page, I saw this: `var session = 'yadda yadda';`

Answer (score 2):

Is it a requirement to pass the session variable to the ASHX, or would it be preferable for the ASHX to be able to access session variables? The latter is more secure and less work. You just need to add an inheritance to the IReadOnlySessionState interface if all it will do is read it. There are other interfaces you can inherit from if you wish to actually change it, but this should get you on the right track. [Here](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/GettingSessionStateInHttpHandlersASHXFiles.aspx) is a link.

Edit: Corrected the link.